# Modifying a class attribute via method decorator

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Test(object):
    data = {}

    @add_to_data(1)
    def method_1(self, x, y):
        pass

    @add_to_data(1, 2, 3)
    def method_2(self, x, y):
        pass

    @add_to_data(5, 6, 7)
    def method_3(self, x, y):
        pass
```

I want it so that at 'import time' the `data` atribute of the class is:

```
>>> Test.data
{'method_1': [1], 'method_2': [1, 2, 3], 'method_3': [5, 6, 7]}
```

Currently I have this (`data` is a `defaultdict`):

```
def add_to_data(*items):
    def decorator(func):
        for item in items:
            name = func.__name__
            cls = ??
            cls.data[name].append(item)
        return func
    return decorator
```

But I don't know how to get the class object. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't particularly clean, but you can do this using `sys._getframe()` to inspect the calling scope (the decorator will be called in the context of the class definition, where `data` is a local variable.

So something like the following should work:

```
import sys

def add_to_data(*items):
    def decorator(func):
        name = func.__name__
        data = sys._getframe(1).f_locals.get('data')
        if data is not None:
            data.setdefault(name, []).extend(items)
        return func
    return decorator
```

If you don't want to depend on `sys._getframe` or want something more explicit, you could make your `@add_to_data` function decorator simply mark the methods with an appropriate function attribute and then use a class decorator to build the `data` dictionary from all the marked methods.

Comment: I didn't think about `sys._getframe()`; you're right, that will work.

Comment: I first saw this trick while reading the `zope.interface` source code.  It is the kind of trick where users of the decorator look quite clean but the implementation can be difficult for others to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because the class object doesn't exist yet.

You probably could do something similar by either creating a base class that has a `@classmethod` to use as a decorator in subclasses, or a decorator that stores things somewhere else together with a class decorator or metaclass that copies the storage into the class's `data` attribute later.

Well, really, without knowing what your actual goal is—and whether you're on Py2 or Py3 (and whether you only care about CPython or any Python)—it's hard to know what to suggest.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054372/auto-register-class-methods-using-decorator