# Registering methods with decorator at class level

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, decorator

I'd like to be able to register/return methods at a class level. The closest answer I could find was here: [Auto-register class methods using decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054372/auto-register-class-methods-using-decorator), except it was centered on a global register and I'm looking for something specific to the class per below.

Code:

```
class ExampleClass:

    def get_reports(self):
        # return list of all method names with @report decorator 
        pass

    def report(self):
        # decorator here
        pass

    @report
    def report_x(self):
        return

    @report
    def report_y(self):
        return

    def method_z(self):
        pass
```

where I'd like `ExampleClass.get_reports()` to return `['report_x', 'report_y']`.

Not all reports will be preceded with `report_`, so there is likely no way to just look at method names. I'm trying to figure out how to do this to apply to a variety of situations, so just looking for `'report_'` does not work in this context.

Comment: Would a manual list not suffice? E.g. `return [report_x, report_y, ...]`? It sounds like you have some sort of manual selection process anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a Reporter class like this and use an instance as a class property. I used the `__call__` override to shorten the decorator, but you can name the function `report` and decorate methods as `@report.report`

```
class Reporter:
    def __init__(self):
         # Maintain a set of reported methods
        self._reported = set()

    def __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        # Register method
        self._reported.add(fn.__name__)
        def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorate    

class ExampleClass:
    report = Reporter()

    def get_reports(self):
         # return list of all method names with @report decorator 
         return list(self.report._reported)

    @report
    def report_x(self):
        return

    @report
    def report_y(self):
        return

    def method_z(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Nice Answer.  In your `__call__` there is no point in `def decorate`  you can simply return the original function.  See my answer for an example.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be similar to [Mach_Zero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359555/7311767).  So key differences, this returns the methods, not the method names, and the implementation of `get_reports()` is somewhat simpler with the use of `__iter__`.

#### Code:

```
class Reports:

    def __init__(self):
        self.reports = []

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.reports.append(func)
        return func

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.reports)


class ExampleClass:

    report = Reports()

    @classmethod
    def get_reports(cls):
        # return list of all method names with @report decorator
        return list(cls.report)

    @report
    def report_x(self):
        return

    @report
    def report_y(self):
        return

    def method_z(self):
        pass
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(ExampleClass.get_reports())
```

#### Results:

```
[
    <function ExampleClass.report_x at 0x000000000AF7B2F0>, 
    <function ExampleClass.report_y at 0x000000000AF7B378>
]
```