# The elegant way to mark a set of member functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a class `Tool` whose some member functions will be processed by another class, so I want to mark them explicitly and elegantly. For example,

```py
class Tool:
    def __init__(self):
        self._marked = []

    @mark # how to add func1 to self._marked?
    def func1():
        """I will be processed"""
    
    def func2():
        """I will not be processed"""

    def marked_funcs():
        """return all marked functions"""
        return self._marked
```

However, the function decorator `mark` cannot access `self`, so I cannot add the decorated functions to `self._marked`. How can I do this, or is there any other elegant way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Since the methods are static, since they don't take `self`, I don't even see an option how to adjust `self._marked`. I assume this is a mistake , and the function method should at least be `def func1(self, ...)` and similar for the other two methods?

Comment: @9769953 They actually aren't static and will not work in any way. Static methods need appriopriate decorator.

Comment: Instead of `self._marked` and `marked_funcs` on the class you are marking, a decorator like this would normally "register" whatever it is applied to into a global variable. See this tutorial https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-ultimate-guide-to-python-decorators-part-i-function-registration  You hay also find this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/3054505/202168

Comment: @matszwecja Whoops, my mistake. Although my main point was of course the lack of self, which I turned automatically into "static", while I probably should have said "author mistake" or similar ( as per the second sentence).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is close to what you want to achieve.

- I find it difficult to design a decorator to edit the class object (`self._marked` in the original code). So I create a "global" storage for the marked functions (`_marked`).
- When invoking the `mark` decorator, this function is added to the `_marked` set.
- I define the `marked_funcs` as a class method. This is because what the decorator receive is `Tool.func1`, not the method of the instance.
- As a result, `_marked_funcs` returns its member functions that are marked.

```py
_marked = set()

def mark(func):
    _marked.add(func)
    return func

def is_marked(func):
    return callable(func) and (func in _marked)
  
# test
@mark
def one():
    return 1
is_marked(one)
# True
```

```py
class Tool:
    @mark # how to add func1 to self._marked?
    def func1():
        """I will be processed"""
    
    def func2():
        """I will not be processed"""

    @classmethod
    def marked_funcs(cls):
        """return all marked functions"""
        out = []
        for name in dir(cls):
            obj = getattr(cls, name)
            if is_marked(obj):
                out.append(obj)
        return out

t = Tool()
t.marked_funcs()
# [<function __main__.Tool.func1()>]

Tool.marked_funcs()
# [<function __main__.Tool.func1()>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple idea and it works. There is no need to use a list to store marked functions. I can add new property to the functions that I need to mark, and when necessary, I search for functions which has this property through traversal. For example:

```py
def register(func):
    func.x = 1
    return func


class A:
    @register
    def hello1(self, a, b, c):
        print(f"a={a}, b={b}, c={c}")

    @register
    def hello2(self, a, b, c):
        print(f"a={a}, b={b}, c={c}")

    def registered_functions(self):
        res = []
        for func_name in dir(self):
            func = getattr(self, func_name)
            if hasattr(func, 'x'):
                res.append(func)
        return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print(a.registered_functions())
    # [<bound method A.hello1 of <__main__.A object at 0x7f7bd815aca0>>, <bound method A.hello2 of <__main__.A object at 0x7f7bd815aca0>>]
```