# Decorate a decorator: how to assign functionality to adecorator programatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a class where I want some methods to be registered under a set of categories. To do so, I build a set of decorator functions, one for each category I want to then apply them kinda following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054372/auto-register-class-methods-using-decorator). That leads me to defining my category decorators as such:

```py
# The categories
def bar(func):
    func._bar = None
    return func

def foo(func):
    func._foo = None
    return func
```

which are then used inside my class to register some functions like so:

```py
@class_register_categories
class MyClass(object):

    @foo
    def my_method(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
    
    @foo
    @bar
    def my_other_method(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
```

This works fantastic so far, with some extra code modified from the linked answer. I now would like to make it a tiny bit easier to add new categories. Since all decorator functions I define have always the same functionality (grab the input function, add a new attribute to them with a dummy value and return it), I thought it could abstract that to a decorator and *decorate the decorators*. I tried to do that like so:

```py
def category(cat_name_func):
    cat_name = cat_name_func.__name__
    def wrapper(func):
        setattr(func, cat_name, None)
        return func
    return wrapper

@category
def foo(func):
    pass

@category
def bar(func):
    pass
```

But this doesn't work. Doing

```py
@foo
def my_method():
    pass
```

does not add the required attribute to the decorated function.

---

For completeness: full working code. Above I extracted the bits I want to modify from here.

```py
def class_register_categories(cls):
    categories = 'foo', 'bar'
    
    for category in categories:
        setattr(cls, category, Category())
    
    for methodname in dir(cls):
        method = getattr(cls, methodname)
        for category in categories:
            if hasattr(method, '_'+category):
                getattr(cls, category).append(methodname)
        
    return cls

class Category(list):
    
    def __repr__(self):
        string = '\n'.join(self)
        return string

def foo(func):
    func._foo = None
    return func

def bar(func):
    func._bar = None
    return func


@class_register_categories
class MyClass(object):

    @foo
    def my_method(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
    
    @foo
    @bar
    def my_other_method(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass
    
    def yet_another_method(self):
        pass
    
myclass = MyClass()
print(myclass.foo)
# my_method
# my_other_method
```

Comment: You can give parameters to a decorator. Could you use that instead of multiple decorator functions?

Comment: Did you just forget the underscore? `setattr(func, "_" + cat_name, None)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I run the "this doesn't work" block (after the code block right above it), it works as I'd expect. The `my_method` function gets a `foo` attribute set to `None`. Perhaps you've confused something between the version that set `_foo` and the one that sets `foo`?

Comment: Oh crap. You know when you are so deep in the code you miss stuff like that? Thanks a lot, I know this is not a proofreading service. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments stating you forgot the underscore.

While the following code can fix it:

```
def category(cat_name_func):
    cat_name = "_" + cat_name_func.__name__
    def wrapper(func):
        setattr(func, cat_name, None)
        return func
    return wrapper
```

I highly disagree with the design of the code. You're creating unnecessary attributes that you're not using, and a function which doesn't do much, just in order to use the decorator syntax. It feels like you're forcing the code to behave in an inelegant way. It may be due to a minimalist example created for stackoverflow, but if not, I'd suggest some refactoring.

Here is one possible way:

```
def category(name: str, /):
    def decorator(func):
        try:
            func._categories.add(name)
        except AttributeError:
            func._categories = {name}
        return func
    return decorator

def register_categories(cls):
    categories: dict[str, set[str]] = {}
    # Get all methods and their categories
    for name, method in cls.__dict__.items():
        if hasattr(method, '_categories'):
            for category in method._categories:
                categories.setdefault(category, set()).add(name)

    # Create the category attributes from the aggregated categories
    for category, methods in categories.items():
        setattr(cls, category, methods)

    return cls

foo = category('foo')

@register_categories
class A:

    @foo
    def a(self):
        pass

    def b(self):
        pass

    @category('bar')
    def c(self):
        pass
```

This lets you create dynamic categories (`bar`), create shortcuts for them (`foo`) and register them dynamically.

You can create a set of categories add to it using the `category()` function if you wish to always have all categories, even empty ones, on every class.

I further suggest not to use an attribute per category, but a general `.categories` attribute on the class, as that can prevent you from namespace collisions (such as a function named `foo()` and a category named `foo`)

Comment: I agree my approach was inelegant. Building the decorator builder `category` was what I needed to make the refactor into exactly what you did. I just went with the other approach to avoid having each category be a decorator with the exact same code implementing the try except block and everything else. But props to you for an answer and also implementing the next step.